# Updating a specific type of fields in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I found this reference that will update all fields in a word document. http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm

```
Sub UpdateAll()
    Dim oStory As Range
    For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        oStory.Fields.Update
        If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
            While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
                Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
                oStory.Fields.Update
            Wend
        End If
    Next oStory
    Set oStory = Nothing
End Sub
```

I would like to modify it to only fields of the `DocProperty` type update using this macro.

For example: I would like to update all `DocProperty` types while skipping all `Ref` types or all other types for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check the fields `Type` property before updating, but you will have to loop through them.

There are many ways to do this, but I put the loop in a sub, so you can just change your *two update-lines* from

```
oStory.Fields.Update
```

to

```
Call UpdateRangeFieldsOfType(oStory, wdFieldDocProperty)
```

Here's the sub:

```
Sub UpdateRangeFieldsOfType(poRange As Range, peType As WdFieldType)
    Dim oField As Field

    For Each oField In poRange.Fields
        If oField.Type = peType Then
            oField.Update
        End If
    Next
    Set oField = Nothing
End Sub
```